How to generate a JWT for Apple App Store Connect API?
The App Store Connect API requires a JSON Web Token (JWT) to authorize each request you make to the API.
How do I generate this JWT in Go?

func GetJwtToken() {
    header := map[string]interface{}{
        "alg": "ES256",            // Algorithm
        "kid": os.Getenv("KEYID"), // Key ID (replace with your actual Key ID)
        "typ": "JWT",
    }

    // Define custom payload
    payload := jwt.MapClaims{
        "iss": os.Getenv("ISSUER_ID"),      // Issuer (replace with your actual Team ID)
        "iat": time.Now().Unix(),           // Issued At Time
        "exp": time.Now().Add(1800).Unix(), // Expiration Time (within 30 minutes)
        "aud": "appstoreconnect-v1",        // Audience
        "bid": os.Getenv("BUNDLE_ID"),      // Subject (replace with your actual Client ID)
    }

        // Read the private key from file
        privateKeyBytes, err :=
        os.ReadFile("privateKeys/SubscriptionKey_ISSUER_ID.p8")

    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error reading private token file: %v", err)
    }

    block, _ := pem.Decode(privateKeyBytes)
    if block == nil {
        fmt.Println("Error decoding private key PEM")
        return
    }

    privateKey, err := x509.ParsePKCS8PrivateKey(block.Bytes)
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error parsing private key:", err)
        return
    }

    ecKey, ok := privateKey.(*ecdsa.PrivateKey)
    if !ok {
        fmt.Println("Error casting private key to ECDSA")
        return
    }

    // Sign JWT token
    token := jwt.New(jwt.SigningMethodES256)
    token.Header = header
    token.Claims = payload

    tokenString, err := token.SignedString(ecKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatalf("Error signing token: %v", err)
        return
    }
    fmt.Println("JWT Token:", tokenString)
}

